# Attempt to Load Mobilenet results in Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html, mobilenet

I'm getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError` when I try to load this script, any suggestions?

> `index.html:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: mobilenet is not defined
>       at index.html:12`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Something else Introduction</title>
        <!----  Import Script---->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.2.8" type="text/javascript" </script>                   
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet@2.0.4" type="text/javascript"</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="img" crossOrigin src = "https://i.imgur.com/e5KD2lt.jpg">
        <h1 id="message">Hello, I'm a simple web page!</h1>
        <script>
            mobilenet.load().then(net => {
            console.log('Model loaded to memory!')
            const theImage = document.getElementById('img')
        net.classify(theImage).then(result=> {
            document.getElementById('message').innerText = `
                Detected: ${result[0].className}
                Probability: ${result[0].Probability}
                `
            })
        })   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This means mobilenet loads after your code or as it happens with unpkg.com mobilnet is not a global function.

Comment: You can try async import to control it `(async function() {
  let run;
  ({run} = (await import('https://coffeescript.org/browser-compiler-modern/coffeescript.js')));
  return run('if 5 < new Date().getHours() < 9\n  alert \'Time to make the coffee!\'\nelse\n  alert \'Time to get some work done.\'');
})();` or just use fetch `fetch('https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet@2.0.4').then(r=>r.text()).then((a)=>{const x = new Function('lol', a); x()})`

Answer (score 1):

Just change in your `<head>` tags as the following:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.2.8" type="text/javascript"></script>                   
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet@2.0.4" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Additional suggestion:**

Use your `<script>` tags at the end of `<body>` tag and not in the `<head>` or just simply use [`async`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) attribute. It will help the page load performance. Read further [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup/24070373#24070373) for longer explanation.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The script tags are missing closing brackets